# How should I store multiple sessions in Redis?

Tags: session, redis, token

I am new to the Redis. I want to store the user id / session token pairs on the Redis. But, A user can have multiple session tokens. For example, you might think that when the user changes their password, I want to delete all session pairs of this user. *Also, each session pair must have an expiration date. The method to be recommended should not spoil this.*

How can I do this most effectively and correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sorted set for this

`key`: `user:<id>:tokens`

member name is token, member score is its expire timestamp

- add a new token `zadd <key> <token> <expire_timestamp>`
- to get all tokens for user `zrange user:1:tokens 0 -1`. Add `WITHSCORES` if you need expiration timestamp along with the token.
- to get tokens with valid time `zrangebyscore <key> <current_ts> +inf`
- to delete all tokens `del <key>`

Example of cleanup code

```js
async function getTokens(userId) {
    const lastCleanupTsKey = `user:${userId}:tokens:cleants`
    const tokenKey = `user:${userId}:tokens`

    cosnt [[lastCleanTimestamp, err1], [size, err2] = await redis.pipeline()
        .get(lastCleanupTsKey)
        .zcount(tokenKey)
        .exec()

    if (!lastCleanTimestamp) {
        await redis.set(lastCleanupTsKey, <current_timestamp>)
    }

    if (size !== null && size > CLEANUP_SIZE_THRES_HOLD) { // you can also check if lastCleanup is more than 5 minutes for example here.
        await redis.ZREMRANGEBYSCORE(tokenKey, '-inf', <current_timestamp>)
    }

    // do your logic
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I understand, the expired items won't be removed automatically in this scenario. The items will stay in the sorted set unless I delete them manually. I'm looking for a less complex solution.

Comment: @jessie.chan redis expiration only work on key level. if you want redis to do the expiration for you, you will have to store the data at key level.

Comment: I know but in that scenario the finding the keys from the values looks expensive to handle. I am really confused. Do you have any suggestions to handle that? What is the best practise?

Comment: I have to be able to remove all sessions belongs to a user. If I store tokens as keys. The only common thing is value. It will store something related with user aka user id. So, we need to recognize all of the tokens belongings to this user id. It seems non performant.

Comment: In your scenario, I have to run jobs for a certain amount of time in order to delete expired tokens, otherwise they will stay there permanently. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: yeah, in my scenario, you will have to do a cron job for that. However, doing it is trivial. it might not even be a cronjob. you can do sth like this: when getting token, check if the sorted set size is higher than certain threshold (when you want the clean up to trigger, eg: last cleanup is more than 1 hour or size > 100) => zrangebyscore and then delete